# Orientation of graphs without transitive triangles

Tags: graph-theory

Consider undirected graphs which can be endowed an orientation such that every triangle is cyclic. If a graph cannot have such an orientation, then the same is true for any graph containing it as a subgraph. When finding forbidden subgraphs, we may consider only connected graphs with every edge in a triangle.

Among the wheel graphs, all odd wheels are forbidden, while all even wheels are not.

Consider a strip of $n$ triangles, and glue together the two ends like a Möbius strip, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rolxb.png). Then for $n \ge 5$, all even $n$'s are forbidden while all odd $n$'s are not.

If we consider wheel graphs as a strip of triangles with two ends glued together like a cylinder, and then with top edges contracted to a point, the above two cases can be unified: Take a strip of triangles like in the image and contract some top and bottom edges. If it has an odd number of triangles left, it is forbidden when the two ends are glued like a cylinder, but not forbidden when glued like a Möbius strip, and vice versa.

Are there other forbidden subgraphs? Can we give a forbidden subgraph characterisation of this type of undirected graphs?

Comment: I don't see how you can contract the edge of a triangle, as that would merge together the other two edges of the triangle which are oriented in opposite directions. But sure, any strip of triangles, whichever edges they are connected on, must have alternating orientations, so when connected into a ring, the ends have to be oriented according to the parity.

Comment: Yes, so we are contracting the edges before giving them a direction.

Comment: I think you're right that the minimal forbidden subgraphs are exactly those loops of triangles with the wrong combination of parity and twist, and that the undirected graphs that can be given an orientation such that all triangles are cyclic are characterised by the absense of such forbidden subgraphs. It seems intuitively obvious, but no doubt it will take a bit of work to make fully rigorous.